# Display all parent elements of current element's information like name, class, id or any other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I would like to know how would it be possible to get current element's information along with all the parent elements till body tag on given html page. I would like to display it's full path and show class/id of current element plus any of the parent's attributes like class and id information. Also i would like to know what is the current element which is being hovered e.g. it's div, p, a, li, ul, input or anything else.

If anyone can just give me direction or some hint's will be helpful. I was able to fetch current element's information without any issue but couldn't find which is the current element.

Please provide your suggestions too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @rory-mccrossan checking it.

Comment: prevAll returns all previous _siblings_ not parents

Comment: Have a look in the API for `parents` and `each`. @foobar yep, just realised myself :)

Comment: No attempt on your side?!

Comment: I am trying to check with javascript, jquery but not able to find a concrete solution

Comment: Are you familiar with jquery ?

Comment: @f00bar yes, what I want to do is to setup some customized javascript code on interaction of elements but for that I am stuck at finding current element as based on element i would have different customization.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gK6sp/ this is what i was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have coded a jQuery plugin for debugging purpose few weeks ago ...

Test Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/dC857/)

```
(function ($) {
    var getInfos = function () {
        var id = this.attr('id'),
            classes = this.attr('class');
        return [this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() + (id ? '#' + id : '') + (classes ? '.' + classes.replace(/ +(\w)/, '.$1') : '')];
    }
    $.fn.getParentsStack = function () {
        if (!this.length) return '';
        var $t = this.eq(0),
            list = [getInfos.apply($t)];
        $t.parentsUntil('html').each(function (i, el) {
            list.push(getInfos.apply($(this)));
        });
        return list.reverse().join(' > ');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks @f00bar checking your code too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gK6sp/4/ my customisation

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = "";
function func(n,id) {
    if(!n) {
        n = document.getElementById(id);
    }
    if(n.tagName.toLowerCase()!='html') {
        txt += n.tagName+" with id="+(n.id?n.id:"<no id>")+" classes="+(n.className?n.className:"<no classes>")+"\n";
        func(n.parentNode,n.parentNode.id);
    }
}
```

Initially call the function with n as 'null' and pass the id of the node. Or, if you have the reference of the node, you can pass. THe reason why both are given is, some elements might not have id. some might. that's why. Check out a sample here -

http://jsfiddle.net/L8WhS/

Comment: Thanks, @vivek_nk checking your code